# Citation Feature Request

Tags: feature-request

As the field of Quantum Computing is still being established, I believe that the cite feature such as that found on Physics.SE would be helpful. This would allow scholars and professionals to easily cite questions and answers that have been provided on this website.

### The Proposal

Implementation of a cite feature that allows scholars and students to see how an individual would properly cite a question or answer provided on this website.

### *Example Implementation*

This Physics.SE meta [Post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4191) is an example of how it could be implemented.

Comment: Can you please edit to give the link to the referenced feature on pyhsics.se

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver An example of the cite link can be found at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/cooling-a-cup-of-coffee-with-help-of-a-spoon#cite-link-5265. By clicking the cite button, a popup window appears with an example citation.

Comment: @DanielBurkhart I think Gypsy is asking for the meta post on physics.meta.se regarding that feature, if tehre is one.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver if Riker is right this is the link you request: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/do-we-want-the-citation-tool-from-math-se

Comment: @MEE What I was looking for was how it works, and the comment from the OP gave that. Still, the meta post is nice to see as well. And includes good arguments in favor of the feature that applies to here as well. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @MEE Yeah, that is exactly what I was referring too.

Answer (score 4):

## I agree with this proposal

There is likely to be a reasonable amount of content created here that is worthy of citing. Enabling the "cite" feature make it easier to know how to properly cite. It also helps to remove the barrier some future authors might feel against posting content when they are not sure how it will be attributed if it is used later.

Having the this feature will also make it clear "how" content should be cited, which is often a problem people face when dealing with Internet content. So often where it comes from might have many unknown rules buried in assorted policies and "agreements." The "cite" feature makes it official in one easily found location, exactly what is expected by the site for citations from the site and its content.